# Unable to access windows 10 even after boot repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I did a dual boot to install Ubuntu by partitioning off Windows 10. After installation, I was not able to see the Windows 10 loader in grub menu at the start. So I did a boot repair following the instructions given on Ubuntu. Now I have more options in the grub menu at the beginning but still not able to see the Windows 10 loader option.

Please help to figure out my next steps from here. This is what i can see in the grub menu now:
[image: Photo Grub boot screen]

Comment: Heh, posting of screenshots moved to the next level… :-D

Answer (score 2):

The **Windows Boot Manager** (as shown in your image) is your Windows 10 boot menu.  That is the way it's named in the UEFI configuration.